# Getting started on Corda on Windows

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I am trying to get started on Corda on Windows and I am following the started guides using the following docs:

- https://docs.corda.net/quickstart-index.html#setting-up-a-development-environment
- https://vimeo.com/217462250
- https://docs.corda.net/getting-set-up.html

I have downloaded all the latest version (as of 22.09.19) of Git (2.23.0, 64-bit version) / Java JDK (jdk-8u221-windows-x64.exe) / and the latest IntelliJ.

However I am facing the following issues:

1. When I open the 'Event Log' I don't see any messages event gradle message
2. Also when I try and run the Nodes from Intellj > Run CordaApps Kotlin I get the following error message:
3. When I try and run the nodes from the Git bash terminal

   ```
   Jatin@LAPTOP-16QRBJDJ MINGW64 ~/cordapp-tutorial (release-V3)

   $ ./gradlew.bat deployNodes
   Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 stopped Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
   :java-source:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
   :java-source:processResources UP-TO-DATE
   :java-source:classes UP-TO-DATE
   :java-source:configureCordappFatJar
   :java-source:jar UP-TO-DATE
   :java-source:deployNodes
   Bootstrapping local network in C:\Users\Jatin\cordapp-tutorial\java-source\build\nodes
   Node config files found in the root directory - generating node directories
   Generating directory for Notary
   Generating directory for PartyA
   Generating directory for PartyB
   Generating directory for PartyC
   Nodes found in the following sub-directories: [Notary, PartyA, PartyB, PartyC]
   Waiting for all nodes to generate their node-info files...
   :java-source:deployNodes FAILED

   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

   * What went wrong:
   Execution failed for task ':java-source:deployNodes'.
   > Node in Notary exited with 1 when generating its node-info - see logs in C:\Users\Jatin\cordapp-tutorial\java-source\build\nodes\Notary\logs

   * Try:
   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

   * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

   BUILD FAILED in 23s
   5 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 3 up-to-date
   ```

   The log:

   ```
   CAPSULE EXCEPTION: Illegal char <"> at index 34: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin" (for stack trace, run with -Dcapsule.log=verbose)
   USAGE: <options> corda.jar

     Actions:
     capsule.version - Prints the capsule and application versions.
     capsule.modes - Prints all available capsule modes.
     capsule.jvms - Prints a list of all JVM installations found.
     capsule.help - Prints this help message.

     Options:
     capsule.mode=<value> - Picks the capsule mode to run.
     capsule.reset - Resets the capsule cache before launching. The capsule to be re-extracted (if applicable), and other possibly cached files will `enter code here`be recreated.
     capsule.log=<value> (default: quiet) - Picks a log level. Must be one of none, quiet, verbose, or debug.
     capsule.java.home=<value> - Sets the location of the Java home (JVM installation directory) to use; If 'current' forces the use of the JVM that launched  the capsule.
     capsule.java.cmd=<value> - Sets the path to the Java executable to use.
     capsule.jvm.args=<value> - Sets additional JVM arguments to use when running the application."
   ```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: halfer - can you please confirm what my  next steps are? How can get this example to  work?

Comment: I have removed it.. please advise what the next steps are?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set Java classpath to point to jdk1.8.0_221?

From the log record it seems that the jdk is 1.7. Corda require at least version 8u171. Please check the classpath and installed java version.

You should add Java to the PATH environment variable by following the instructions in the Oracle documentation - "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html#path"

Answer (score 0):

Which java variant you are using?

If it is Adopt OpenJDK 8, use **HotSpot JVM** not the OpenJ9 Version.

Here is the link for windows x64 [AdoptOpenJDK 8](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=hotspot#x64_win)